# Чем является в предложении "но реже"

Tags: синтаксис

> В лощине, на пустом месте, тоже рвались снаряды, но реже, зато на высотке с тремя домиками, над позициями соседних взводов, стоял сплошной дым.

Answer (score 1):

Союз НО обычно соединяет или однородные члены предложения, или части сложносочинённого предложения. Здесь союз НО присоединяет неполное предложение РЕЖЕ. 
Ср.:  В лощине тоже рвались снаряды, но [рвались они]реже.

Comment: Почему именно предложение?

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, Вы имели в виду "но реже"? Это похоже на неполное предложение с пропуском слов "они рвались", которые восстанавливаются по предыдущей части предложения. Но в неполном предложении должен быть хотя бы один главный член. По этой причине можно рассматривать "но реже" как присоединительную конструкцию, которая обособляется

Comment: Простите, Виктор, но в неполном предложении может и не быть главного члена. Например: Когда вернётесь? - ЗАВТРА.

Comment: Спасибо, Катя! Я такого примера не нашел, поэтому сомневался в том, что указанное предложение неполное. Пример в Вашем ответе развеял мои сомнения, и я возвращаюсь к своей первой версии о неполном предложении.

Answer (score 0):

Обстоятельством. "Но" здесь, конечно, союз, но присоединяет всего лишь отдельный член предложения: тоже ..., но реже.

Answer (score 0):

это присоединительная конструкция, как и здесь: Вопрос нужно рассмотреть, и немедленно;

Comment: Об этом я вчера и писал, что это присоединительная конструкция